# Monitoring, debugging, and tracking CompletableFuture tasks

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future

I would like to monitor, track, and debug my tasks when using CompletableFuture, for example in the following code:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 2)
    .thenApply(i -> i*2)
    .thenAccept(i -> System.out.println("i = " + i));
```

The Javadoc for [CompletableFuture.AsynchronousCompletionTask](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.AsynchronousCompletionTask.html) seems promising, but it is not clear how to use it:

> A marker interface identifying asynchronous tasks produced by async methods. This may be useful for monitoring, debugging, and tracking asynchronous activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Runnables passed to the executor will not be the original Runnables, they will be wrapped into a class that implements AsynchronousCompletionTask, and this makes the tracking possible as in the following code:

```
public class Main {
    private static final Executor tracker = new TrackingExecutor(ForkJoinPool.commonPool());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 2, tracker)
            .thenApply(i -> i*2)
            .thenAccept(i -> System.out.println("i = " + i));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}

class TrackingExecutor implements Executor {
    private Executor delegate;

    public TrackingExecutor(Executor delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable task) {
        if(task instanceof CompletableFuture.AsynchronousCompletionTask) {
            System.out.println("executing CompletableFuture task");
        }
        delegate.execute(task);
    }
}
```